# WPF DataTemplate for Different Principals

Tags: c#, wpf

as you know, there's a way to bind DataTemplate to a specific DataType. Thats exactly what i want for `UserPrincipal` and `GroupPrincipal` from `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`

My Problem is to access the Types.

```
xmlns:ds="clr-namespace:System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;assembly=System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement"
```

[...]

```
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="ds:UserPrincipal">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="ds:GroupPrincipal">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

Why doesn't this work? Is there another possibility to show these Properties according to the DataType of the object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DataType` property of a DataTemplate requires an explicit `{x:Type ...}` expression.

That's because its type is `object`, in contrast to e.g. the `TargetType` property of a Style, which is of type `Type`. Without the `{x:Type ...}` the property value is just a string.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ds:UserPrincipal}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ds:GroupPrincipal}">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```